# Rank of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, rank

I want to test the rank of a matrix, is there someone who can recommend a package/function in R for this?

Answer (score 42):

You can try the function `qr` ("qr", because it performs a [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)):

```
#define a matrix for this example
M <- matrix(data = rnorm(12), ncol = 3)

#run the function qr() 
qr(M)$rank

#Alternative: load the Matrix package...
require(Matrix)

#...and run the function rankMatrix()
rankMatrix(M)[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/Matrix.pdf, page 101

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixcalc/matrixcalc.pdf, page 12

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Library pracma: Practical Numerical Math (Provides a large number of functions from numerical analysis and linear algebra, numerical optimization, differential equations, time series, plus some well-known special mathematical functions.).

Install it using the below command in the R console:
        install.packages("pracma", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
You can use the library then :
        library(pracma)
         Rank(Your Matrix object)